# Warning when retrieving Metadata from remote webpage

Tags: php, curl, warnings, metadata, web-crawler

I am getting these two errors when retrieving meta data from a remote webpage. Is this an escaping issue or maybe a cURL issue?

```
Warning: get_meta_tags(<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://...@import url( "http://www.zymic.com/forum/style_images/v6/folder_editor_images/css_rte.css" ); </style> </head> <body> <div id="ipbwrapper"> <!--ipb.javascript.start--> <script type="text/javascript"> //<![CDATA[ var ipb_var_st = "0"; var ipb_lang_tpl_q1 = "Please enter a page number to jump to between 1 and"; var ipb_var_s = "f2e0d2b492f248ec27ef34ae291a1db4"; var ipb_var_phpext = "php"; var ipb_var_base_url = "http://www.zymic.com/forum/index.php?s=f2e0d2b492f248ec27ef34ae291a1db4&"; var ipb_var_image_url = "style_images/v6"; var ipb_input_f = "34"; var ipb_input_t = "5188"; var ipb_input_p = ""; var ipb_var_cookieid
= ""; var ipb_var_cookie_ in public_html/list/main/output.php on line 22 retrieve pagetitle Warning: file_get_contents(<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://...@import url( "http://www.zymic.com/forum/style_images/v6/folder_editor_images/css_rte.css" ); </style> </head> <body> <div id="ipbwrapper"> <!--ipb.javascript.start--> <script type="text/javascript"> //<![CDATA[ var ipb_var_st = "0"; var ipb_lang_tpl_q1 = "Please enter a page number to jump to between 1 and"; var ipb_var_s = "f2e0d2b492f248ec27ef34ae291a1db4"; var ipb_var_phpext = "php"; var ipb_var_base_url = "http://www.zymic.com/forum/index.php?s=f2e0d2b492f248ec27ef34ae291a1db4&"; var ipb_var_image_url = "style_images/v6"; var ipb_input_f = "34"; var ipb_input_t = "5188"; var ipb_input_p = ""; var ipb_var_cookieid
= ""; var ipb_var_coo in /public_html/list/main/output.php on line 27
```

Here is the code:

```
////Use Curl Library to get page content for security
$url = 'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Lists_of_lists';
$curl = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);  
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);  
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'ListBot 1.0: Used for compiling a DB of lists across the internet.'); 
$str = curl_exec($curl);  
curl_close($curl);

//get metadata
$tags = get_meta_tags($str);

//Get page title
function get_page_title($str){

    if( !($data = file_get_contents($str)) ) return false;

    if( preg_match("#<title>(.+)<\/title>#iU", $data, $t))  {
        return trim($t[1]);
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}


        ///////////
        echo('retrieve pagetitle');


$tags['title'] = get_page_title($str);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

get_meta_tags expects a file location (commonly a url).

You could request the url directly and parse the headers, but you'd probably get better results doing a regular expression match on the string you retrieved with curl.

You have a nice bit of code that grabs the title.  Simply modify that to grab all the meta tags.

In the [php.net page describing "get_meta_tags()"](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.get-meta-tags.php) jstel at 126 dot com contributed this nice function call:

> preg_match_all("/<meta[^>]+(http-equiv|name)=\"([^\"]*)\"[^>]" . "+content=\"([^\"]*)\"[^>]*>/i", $v, $split_content[], PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);

Which will search string $v for meta data and dump matches into $split_content.  In his sample he does a bunch of looping that seems unneeded, but I'd suggest looking at his code and seeing if you can adapt it.